# Using observables to search OMDB API to retrieve movies info

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

hey guys I am trying to do a live search using Observables in Angular2 to retrieve Movie information from OMDB API. I can see that it is working in Chrome Network tab but I dont get the results in UI.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'movie-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html'
})
export class Component implements OnInit{
  movies: Observable<Array<Movie>>;
  search = new FormControl;

  constructor(private service: MovieService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.movies = this.search.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(search => this.service.get(search))
  }
}
```

MovieService

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
  constructor (private http: Http) { }
  get(path: string){
    return this.http
      .get('www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + path)
      .map((res) => res.json())
  }
}
```

and in my HTML Component I have an input and then the UI to display the results.

```
<input [formControl]="search"> 

<div *ngFor="let movie of movies | async">

<h1>{{movie.title}}</h1>
```

When I am inputing I see the results in my Network Tab, like this:

[image]

But it is not displayed in the UI. Can someone help please? Thanks

Comment: Could you include the `@Component` decorator so that it's clear whether or not you are using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for the component? And how is `MovieService` implemented? Using Angular's `Http` service?

Comment: Could you confirm that the template is valid and that you have a closing `</div`> tag in there? Or include the whole thing in the question.

Comment: yes the template is 100% valid.

Comment: Could you include in your the version of Angular2 that you are using? The problem is likely related to change detection not being triggered, but I'm a little curious as to why that's the case, as it all looks okay.

Comment: I am using the latest version of angular

Comment: Your service is needs to return the `Search` property of the `json` result; the result itself is not an array; it's an object. See [`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=jason%20bourne`](http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=jason%20bourne)

Comment: how do i make it return that search object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service you are using returns a JSON object - not an array. For example, [`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=jason%20bourne`](http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=jason%20bourne) will return something like:

```
{
  "Search": [
    {
      "Title": "Jason Bourne",
      "Year": "2016",
      "imdbID": "tt4196776",
      "Type": "movie",
      "Poster": "https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTU1ODg2OTU1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzA5OTg2ODE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "totalResults": "16",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

So if your service is supposed to return an array of movies, it should return the `Search` property of the result:

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
  constructor (private http: Http) { }
  get(path: string){
    return this.http
      .get('www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + path)
      .map((res) => res.json().Search || [])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way worked for me: in angular 6

Service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/RX';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

 export class omdbService {
 searchMovieByTitle(title: String) {
 const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + title + '&apikey=da53126b';
  return this.http.get(url).map( (response: Response ) => {
   return response.json();  } ); }

   constructor (private http: Http) { }
   }
```

HTML file:

```
     <label>movietitle</label>
      <input #input class="form-control" />
       <button mdbBtn type="button" color="info" outline="true" mdbWavesEffect
           (click)="searchMovie(input.value)" >
         Search
        </button>

     <ul class="list-group">
       <li  class="list-group-item" *ngFor =" let movie of result.Search" >
           {{movie.Title}}   {{movie.imdbID}}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Ts file:

```
import { omdbService } from './../service/omdb.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
             selector: 'app-search',
             templateUrl: './search.component.html',
             styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
                })

    export class SearchComponent  {

         title  = '';
         result: Object = null;

     searchMovie(title: String) {
        this.OmdbService.searchMovieByTitle(title).subscribe( (result) => {
      this.result = result;     console.log(result);
             });                }

      constructor(private OmdbService: omdbService) { }

        }
```